# Удаление из массива Javascript

Tags: javascript

Это код класса

```
function TextMessage(text, x, y, duration, color) {
        this.text = text;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.color = color;
        this.destr = function () {
            text_messages.splice(text_messages.indexOf(this), 1);
        }
        setTimeout(this.destr, this.duration);
    }
```

Вот так его рисую:

```
for (i=0;i<text_messages.length;i++) {
     g_drawtext(text_messages[i].text, text_messages[i].x, text_messages[i].y--, 12, text_messages[i].color);
}
```

Вот так добавляю новый элемент:

```
text_messages.push(new TextMessage("-" + g_map[game_x][game_y].unit.attack_power, selected_unit.x, selected_unit.y, 1000, g_rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)));
```

Но удаляется почему то не тот объект что надо...((

Comment: боюсь что функция destr не вызывается

Попробуйте внутри этой функции вызвать alert("destr");

Comment: var self = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
   self.destr();
  }, this.duration)

вот это спасло отца русской демократии)

Answer (score 4):

`destr` вызывается, вот только `this` указывает не туда, куда надо (отправляется именно функция без привязки к объекту). Прочитайте [вот эту](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2006/07/delegates-in-javascript.html) заметку. Скорее всего, решится добавлением в TextMessage *`var _this = this;`* и использованием `_this` в функции `destr`.

Если не поможет, пишите, попробую еще подсказать.